# failed to get correct core dump from a qt program on cross platform nxp imx6

Tags: c++, qt

I am now working on imx6 platform, an embedded platform which have a qt enviroment.

```
export SDKTARGETSYSROOT=/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
export PATH=/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi:$PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export CONFIG_SITE=/opt/poky/1.7/site-config-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
export OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT="/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux"
export OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT="$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export OECORE_ACLOCAL_OPTS="-I /opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/share/aclocal"
export PYTHONHOME=/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr
export CC="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CXX="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CPP="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export AS="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-as "
export LD="arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ld  --sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export GDB=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gdb
export STRIP=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-strip
export RANLIB=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export OBJCOPY=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
export OBJDUMP=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-objdump
export AR=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar
export NM=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-nm
export M4=m4
export TARGET_PREFIX=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
export CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --build=x86_64-linux --with-libtool-sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export CFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types"
export CXXFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed"
export CPPFLAGS=""
export KCFLAGS="--sysroot=$SDKTARGETSYSROOT"
export OECORE_DISTRO_VERSION="1.7"
export OECORE_SDK_VERSION="1.7"
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-

# Append environment subscripts
if [ -d "$OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d" ]; then
    for envfile in $OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d/*.sh; do
            source $envfile
    done
fi
if [ -d "$OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d" ]; then
    for envfile in $OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d/*.sh; do
            source $envfile
    done
fi
```

I use the below code to catch the core dump, and then I get a log, it can not give  useful information.

```
void dump(int signo)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"catch Segmentation fault!!!\n");

    QDir dir;

    if (!dir.exists("CORE_DUMP_JPG")) {
        system("mkdir CORE_DUMP_JPG");
    }

    if (!dir.exists("CORE_DUMP_LOG")) {
        system("mkdir CORE_DUMP_LOG");
    }
    //截屏
    QPixmap tmpPixmap= grabScreens();
    QDateTime dt = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QString filename = dir.canonicalPath() + "/CORE_DUMP_JPG/CORE_DUMP_" + dt.toString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".jpg";
    tmpPixmap.save(filename, 0, 100);
    qDebug()<<"CORE_DUMP_JPG file name: "<<filename<<endl;

    #define SIZE 5000
    FILE *fh;
    QString logfile = dir.canonicalPath() + "/CORE_DUMP_LOG/coredump.log";

    if(!(fh = fopen(logfile.toStdString().c_str(), "w+"))) {
        system(" echo '打不开cordump.log文件' > /CORE_DUMP_JPG/cor-dump.log");
        exit(0);
    }
    qDebug()<<"CORE_DUMP_LOG file name: "<<logfile<<endl;

    void *buffer[SIZE];
    int nptrs;
    nptrs = backtrace(buffer,SIZE);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(buffer, nptrs, fileno(fh));
    fflush(fh);
    exit(-1);
}

void register_seg_handler()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, &dump);
}

int eg_main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    register_seg_handler();
    __function_make_crash__();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I got the below core dump log file:

```
    ./mhclient[0x1fccec]
    /lib/libc.so.6(__default_sa_restorer+0x0)[0x7421ff80]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
    ./mhclient[0x1aaacc]
```

A sample of the build configuration is :

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot=/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi -c -pipe  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -g -O2 -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -std=c++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKITWIDGETS_LIB -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++ -I. -I/opt/broadcast/muduo-master -I/opt/broadcast/boost_1_58 -I/opt/broadcast/protobuf-2.5/src -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebKitWidgets -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtMultimedia -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebKit -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I/opt/poky/1.7/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
```

Can somebody tell me how to get a useful core dump in such embedded enviroment? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if add  “-funwind-tables” with CC toolchain